# OSError: libusb-1.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory while building docs in readthedocs

Tags: python, python-3.x, libusb, read-the-docs

I am trying to build documentation in readthedocs for a python module.
In my python module, I import libusb using command `import libusb`. libusb package requires a libusb-1.0-0 Debian package which is usually installed via `sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0`.

It seems the readthedocs server doesn't have libusb-1.0-0. Hence I get the following message in readthedocs:

```
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/strym/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from . import libusb1
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/strym/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb1/libusb1.py", line 199, in <module>
    libusb = _loadLibrary()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/strym/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/usb1/libusb1.py", line 173, in _loadLibrary
    return dll_loader('libusb-1.0' + suffix, **loader_kw)
  File "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libusb-1.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As a result, my documentation is not generated. 
How should I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I had given up on that  and later I changed my requirements for not to need libusb. However, now that my understanding has become richer, I can suggest doing something like this:

Add following lines to .travis.yml file:


before_install:
   
 - sudo apt-get -y install libusb-1.0-0-dev

Comment: Sorry, the formatting is not that great in the comments section. I am adding as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Responding to @eric-wiener

I had given up on that and later I changed my requirements for not to need libusb. However, now that my understanding has become richer, I can suggest doing something like this: Add the following lines to the `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install: 
    - sudo apt-get -y install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Let me know if it works. If it works then I can mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: This solved one problem. Now I'm just stuck on a missing GLIBC_2.27 Thanks for your help!